# Can you create a variadic function out of a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variadic, pure-virtual

I have a variadic template function that calls a pure virtual function and passes its variadic parameters into it. Is there any way to turn the virtual function into a variadic function so that I can pass the parameters from the **addComponent** function into the **init** function?

```
class Component {

public:

Entity* entity;
//pure virtual function that needs to be variadic
virtual void init() = 0;

};


template<typename T, typename... TArgs> void addComponent(TArgs&&... MArgs) {

    if(!components.count(typeid(T))) {
        auto c = std::make_unique<T>();
        c->entity = this;
        //passes the variadic parameters from addComponent into init
        c->init(std::forward<TArgs>(MArgs)...);
        components[typeid(T)] = std::move(c);
    }

}

class Sprite : public Component {
//derived function of init accepts different parameters than the pure virtual function in the base class
void init(int x, int y) { 
    //this must be called after the constructor 
    //because entity has no value until after c is constructed
    entity.addComponent<Position>(x, y);
}

};

int main() {
    sprite.addComponent<Sprite>(100, 100); //ERROR
}
```

I know that templates don't work for virtual functions so I can't do it the same way as in the addComponent function. Is there any way for this to be accomplished?

**EDIT:** Sorry if my question was a little bit unclear. The reason that I need an init function is that inside of it I use the member "entity" which is only set *after* the component is constructed. If I try and do the same thing with a constructor it crashes because "entity" is being used before it is given a value.

Comment: why do you need a virtual init function?

Comment: Why would you need an init function in the first place? Initialisation is the job for the constructor.

Comment: The quickest fix for your code is to simply remove the pure virtual `init` from `Component`.  But leave your custom `init` method on Sprite.  But do consider having virtual destructor on the Component base class because I suspect you'll have scenarios that need it ordered object destruction to still work.

Comment: I'm really confused by what `components` is. It looks like some sort of map, so I don't know what happens to it when `addComponent` is invoked twice with the same type. Nor do I know what the `this` pointer is referring to.

Comment: @selbie I need init to be virtual because it needs to be called for ANY derived class of Component. Example: I could also call "sprite.addComponent<Size>()" which would take a different set of arguments to be passed into c->init and call the init function of Size. Also I have a virtual destructor I am just trying to only include necessary pieces of code. If I need to include more I can.

Comment: @selbie addComponent is part of the class "Entity" and it adds a component to an unordered map of components inside of entity. I have if(!components.count[typeid(T))) to make sure that the same component can't be added twice. "this" refers to the "entity" class. If you need I can add more code, I just didn't want to give a massive block of not needed code.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if you cleaned this up into a [mcve].  But what I still don't get is why you say `need init to be virtual because it needs to be called for ANY derived class of Component`  Because your template function (addComponent) is only creating concrete derived classes.  What code path scenario would create something like a Sprite (a class derived from Component), cast it back to a `Component*`, then call the virtual method Init?  I don't get that.  Your `addComponent` function doesn't do that.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I thought that calling c->init would only work if it was from the base class since you don't know what c is, but since c becomes a Sprite object calling c->init calls the sprite version of init not the component version. Thank you this solves my problem. :)